# Android app crashes when sending to different activity

Tags: android, facebook, button

Im trying to use the new material design from google for my new app and first of all could find it in my android studio. So i added a thrid party library.

This solution workt for one screen only when im trying to send it to my next screen(with a facebook login button it crashes).

The library im using is this one:
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/

And im using the normal Facebook SDK

This is my stack trace:

```
02-04 12:33:22.924    3726-3726/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app, PID: 3726
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app/com.example.bart.gp_android_app.login_activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gc.materialdesign.views.
```

**ButtonRectangle cannot be cast to com.facebook.widget.LoginButton**
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at

```
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle cannot be cast to com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            at com.example.bart.gp_android_app.login_activity.onCreate(login_activity.java:130)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What is going on here? i have tried to change the facebook login button this didnt work

the login.xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".InitActivit">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->


<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_test"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            facebook:preset_size="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="86dp" />

        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_below="@+id/speebee"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="SpeeBee"
            android:id="@+id/speebee"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:textColor="#ff350012"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The code where login button var

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
```

The code where its initialized:

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            login_activity.this.user = user;
            updateUI();
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    });
```

These are rules 124 to 132

and this is the handlePendingAction():

```
private void handlePendingAction() {
    PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
    // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
    // will succeed.
    pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;


}
```

As Requested the imports:

```
import com.example.bart.gp_android_app.util.SystemUiHider;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphPlace;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.geniusgentlemen.support_classes.Api;
import com.geniusgentlemen.support_classes.ApiFunctions;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle cannot be cast to com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            at com.example.bart.gp_android_app.login_activity.onCreate(login_activity.java:130)` What's that line?

Comment: will add the login xml. and line 130 is this line: handlePendingAction();

Comment: and post your code too, especially where `login_button` is initialized

Comment: added code . setting the var, where login_button is initialized and the code after line 130

Comment: show  us the imports

Comment: Instead of `createAccount` button use `android.widget.Button` while initializing

Comment: This isnt the solution the error remains the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70221/discussion-between-murtaza-hussain-and-twizzler).

Comment: i found the solution! i imported the wrong view....